# How to verify chain in RemoteCertificateValidationCallback?

Tags: c#, validation, ssl, x509certificate, ca

I have the following code that attempts to verify a server certificate against the CA in my private PKI. Its used with `ServicePointManager` and `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`:

```
static bool VerifyServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    X509Certificate2 ca = new X509Certificate2();
    ca.Import("ca-rsa-cert.der");

    X509Chain chain2 = new X509Chain();
    chain2.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(ca);

    // Check all properties
    chain2.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

    // This setup does not have revocation information
    chain2.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

    chain2.Build(new X509Certificate2(certificate));
    if (chain2.ChainStatus.Length == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    bool result = chain2.ChainStatus[0].Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError;
    Debug.Assert(result == true);

    return result;
}
```

The problem is that `chain2.ChainStatus.Length` is always 0.

If I set `X509RevocationMode` to `X509RevocationMode.Online`, then `ChainStatus.Length == 1` and the status is set to `X509ChainStatusFlags.RevocationStatusUnknown`. (Its expected because there's no revocation in the test rig).

**Question**: What does a 0 length `ChainStatus.Length` mean?

**Question**: If its success, then why is `X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError` not used?

Answer (score 1):

If the `ChainStatuts.Lenght = 0;` that means that your chain is correctly built.
You can also check the result with the `Verify()` function. It use the Online Revocation mode and use the standard policy verification.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, please highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar or using Ctrl+K on your keyboard to nicely format and syntax highlight it!